# Get ruby exception from V8 context

Tags: ruby, v8, therubyracer

```
context = V8::Context.new(timeout: 20000) do |context|
  context['ForbidAccess'] = ->(message) { throw NotImplementedError }
end

begin
  context.eval("ForbidAccess();")
rescue => e
  puts "e.class = #{e.class.name}"
  puts "e.causes = #{e.causes}"
  puts "e.root_cause = #{e.root_cause}"
  puts "e.root_cause.class = #{e.root_cause.class}"
end
```

The console output:

```
e.class = V8::Error
e.causes = [#<V8::Error: uncaught throw NotImplementedError>, #<ArgumentError: uncaught throw NotImplementedError>]
e.root_cause = uncaught throw NotImplementedError
e.root_cause.class = ArgumentError
```

How do I get access to the NotImplementedError object?

(NotImplementedError is just for show. It will get replaced with a custom exception containing a message etc.)

Comment: If am reading your question right you would like to know How to get access to the JavaScript exception inside of your Ruby code that calls it?

Comment: I used 'throw' instead of 'raise'. Thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably aren't doing what you think you are doing. The `throw` keyword is not for exceptions. It is actually a local jump similar to `goto` from other languages. See this snippet:

```
catch :done do
  while true
    array = [1,2,3]
    for i in array
      if i > 2
        throw :done
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is just a control flow structure where the "caught" object must match the "thrown" one. But you can't simply catch all throws and figure out which object it was. For exceptions (like `NotImplementedError`) the correct thing to use is `raise`:

```
context = V8::Context.new(timeout: 20000) do |context|
  context['ForbidAccess'] = ->(message) { raise NotImplementedError }
end

begin
  context.eval("ForbidAccess();")
rescue => e
  puts "e.root_cause = #{e.root_cause.inspect}"
  # correctly prints #<NotImplementedError: NotImplementedError>
end
```

As for why you see `ArgumentError` there, it is simple: A throw can't get through a `begin`-`rescue` structure (that rescues from exceptions). When an uncaught throw meets a rescue, a new exception is created about it. Check below:

```
begin
  throw "whatever"
rescue e
  p e   #=> ArgumentError: uncaught throw "whatever"
end
```

This is what happens [internally](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/blob/8dae8f789014a22512ee3c6f630d8f958e696ab8/lib/v8/error.rb#L97) and all the V8 library see is an `ArgumentError` popping up.

Comment: I am aware of Ruby's raise and JavaScript's throw, but clearly I wasn't  completely awake. Thank you so much for pointing it out.
Also, I doesn't help me that wrote C# several years before ruby, which also uses 'throw' as JavaScript :-)